# What is the correct setup for namespace packages, both installed and as source package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, namespace-package

I have a Python 3.6 virtual environment in which (among others) two libraries are installed that share a common top directory `shared_name`. It does not contain a `__init__.py`. As far as I understand it, that should be an implicit namespace package ([PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/))

When I add to the `PYTHONPATH` a source module that also uses that name at the top level, then I cannot get the latter directory to be found. Python does not find it when both `shared_name` directories have an `__init__.py`, nor when none have it.
Adding `pkgutils.extend()` to one or both `__init__.py` files does not help either.

The structure is like this:

```
lib/python3.6/site-packages/shared_name/p1
lib/python3.6/site-packages/shared_name/p2
source_package/shared_name/infrastructure.py
```

Immediately under `shared_name` there is no `__init__.py` file. At run time, `sys.path` includes `source_package`, but `shared_name.__path__` only contains `lib/python3.6/site-packages/shared_name`, not `source_package`.

I'm at a loss how I can debug it or what might be wrong with it.
Is mixing installed and source packages not allowed for namespace packages? (The documentation seemed silent on this topic to me.)
Using `PYTHONVERBOSE` did not help me either. I don't understand for instance why

```
# destroy shared_name
```

occurs before any evidence that it was tried - let alone matched - at all.

Comment: Please add MVE. It may help in debug.

Comment: I agree about the MVE. The exact imports you're using might play a role. Have you tried putting `infrastructure.py` into `shared_name/p3/`?

Comment: What does "MVE" mean?

Comment: I believe you can get the answers you need from the duplicate I marked. If not, you need to clarify your question with a [**M**inimal **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's unclear exactly how you are importing each and what the directory structures are, and what the expected behavior is.